# How to link a library generated by cmake on other directory?

Tags: c++, cmake

Supppose I have a project with its own `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
project/CMakeLists.txt
```

And I need to compile another Cmake project into a library to use in my project. This other project already has its own `CMakeLists.txt` which is very complex and I want to use it instead of specifying how to build this lib in my own `CMakeLists.txt`.

This seems to be the only way:

`add_subdirectory(/path/to/my/other/project folder_in_my_project)`

but it won't build the outer project first so I can use its generated
   libraries generated in `folder_in_my_project`.

It has to be built first, but it won't be built because of the line

```
add_library(libjrtp STATIC IMPORTED)
SET_PROPERTY(TARGET libjrtp PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION jrtplib/src/libjrtp.a)
```

It requires `libjrtp.a`, but `libjrtp.a` will only be built after everything gets built.

I know I'm asking too much here but there's no documentation about this  behavior on cmake docs

Comment: Link not with the IMPORTED library with given location, but with the library **target**, created in another project. You need to found this target in the other project's `CMakeLists.txt`. If you cannot, then using `add_subdirectory` approach has a little sence - build other project with `ExternalProject_Add` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the library as dependency.

```
add_dependencies(libjrtp)
```

Comment: how am I supposed to specify the path of libjrtp?

Comment: I tried to add below add_subdirectory but I got: add_dependencies called with incorrect number of arguments

Comment: This article has a very good explanation of the whole process.
https://www.selectiveintellect.net/blog/2016/7/29/using-cmake-to-add-third-party-libraries-to-your-project-1. Keywords: `include(ExternalProject)`,